# Would you prefer a public or a private Blockchain for managing identities and the authentification in organisations?

Tags: authentication, blockchain, hyperledger, identity-management, ibm-blockchain

I am working on a blockchain implementation and I'm stucked for weeks now at the decision whether I should use a public or a private Blockchain. It's so difficult to decide. I want to manage the identities across organisations (organisations which working together) in one blockchain so that they can authenticate themselfs with just the one and same identifier on every web service (web services across the organizations).
My first idea was to use a private one because personal data should be private. But at one side if i use the private i would loose the benefits of the original blockchain technology. Also if i use a private i would have again a centralization because someone must manage the access to it? so it would be like a normal database? what would be the benefit then? on the other side if i use a public blockchain i cant control the users who have got access to it and everybody could see the personal data of each employee.

What would you prefer? And also which framework is the best for a quick prototype implementation? I'm thinking about using hyperledger. I'm greatful for every opinion/recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Its opinion based question but I would like to mention my thoughts.*

---

**Regarding security of data on public blockchains, you call always encrypt it.**

> It would be like a normal database?

Most of the private blockchains are [Byzantine fault tolerant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance) and most of the databases are not. Additionally, you can alter data in your database but not in a private blockchain.

> Frameworks best for a quick prototype implementation?

- Public distributed ledgers - Ethereum, Tangle (zero fees, need to POW)
- Private distributed ledgers  - Hyperledger fabric, Bigchaindb

> Which is best?

- **Importance of the data**

  In private blockchains, you are setting up the network. Most of the people, don't set up more than 5-10 nodes. It is highly unlikely that all of them die but possible. In public blockchains, there are thousands of nodes, the probability is dying all of them is very very low.
- **Transaction speed**

  Transaction speed of public ledgers is slower compared to the private ones
- **Cost of the transaction**

  In private blockchains, it's almost zero but significantly higher in public blockchain.